# Jacoco plugin for Sonar doesn't support Spock test

Tags: maven, sonarqube, spock, jacoco

I have a very weird problem with the Jacoco plugin for Sonar.
I have a multi-maven project were I wrote an "Event" class and an "EventTest" class in Spock.
The Jacoco plugin for Sonar doesn't give me any code coverage for the test I made.
If I put a dummy Junit test in the same package, that is not testing anything, the Jacoco plugin show me a coverage of 100% which the coverage I was expecting from my Spock test.
Has anyone ever had the same problem ?

Cheers
Luca

Comment: Never tried using JaCoCo with Spock tests. If you can put a sample project somewhere to reproduce your case (on GitHub for instance), I'd be glad to have a look at it.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thank you for your answer. Basically I have a multi-maven project. The test class I've written using spock is totally ignored if I do not add a Junit test in the same package.If I want to have full coverage, I have to add a Junit test in each package. I googled for one day but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience you can fix this by adding this to the plugins section of the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```